# Lottie + Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, lottie, android-jetpack-compose

How can I use combination of Lottie json animation and Jetpack Compose UI in Android?
I already tried `AndroidView(resId = R.layout.animation)` where is `com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView` with field `lottie_rawRes` but is it the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of compose version alpha05, Lottie seems to be working fine:

```
@Composable
fun CustomView(modifier: Modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()) {
    val visibility = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    val context = ContextAmbient.current
    val customView = remember { LottieAnimationView(context) }
    // Adds view to Compose
    AndroidView({ customView }) { view ->
        // View's been inflated - add logic here if necessary
        with(view) {
            setAnimation(R.raw.choose)
            playAnimation()
            repeatMode = LottieDrawable.INFINITE
            foregroundGravity = Gravity.CENTER
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Lottie compose](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie/blob/master/android-compose.md) has been released:

Dependency:

```
implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie-compose:$lottie_version"
```

Basic usage:

```
val composition by rememberLottieComposition(LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(R.raw.my_animation))
LottieAnimation(composition)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if it is the best way to do it, but that's the current recommmended way to include an Android `View` in a `@Composable` function.

```
@Composable
fun <T : View> AndroidView(
    viewBlock: (Context) -> T,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    update: (T) -> Unit = NoOpUpdate
)
```